# Two different urls in the same Angular 2 project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is it possible to have two different urls for the same Angular 2 project?

For example we have two urls

**(1)** http://example-webapp.com

**(2)** http://example-website.com

If the user is not logged in then go to **(1)** http://example-webapp.com where is a landing page

If it's logged in then go to **(2)** http://example-website.com where is the rest of the app.

Thank you!

Comment: For the specific example you gave, Having two routes ( rather than having two URLs ) would have be better. User arrives at `example-webapp.com/landing` if he is logged in, redirect to  `example-webapp.com/profile`, if he's not, you are already at `example-webapp.com/landing`.

Comment: yes. using two different routes and a 'buffering' component which will redirect the user to the correct route

Comment: It's always possible, not the better way to do it though. This also isn't an Angular question : this is a server question.

Comment: I can't use two routes because I have two different domains

Answer (score 0):

Use a constant.ts file to maintain your base url "http://example-website.com" when user is not logged in, once logged in update the constant value in the file to "http://example-webapp.com".

Use Subject to create a observale object e.g. baseUrl$. Then you can subscribe to it and update its value. All you have to do is write a common service which you can provide in app module and follow procedure reading this link.
[See about Subject here](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/06/25/angular-6-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject)

Answer (score 0):

ng serve --host local-ip-address --public-host http://public-ip-address-or-dns

Where local-ip-address is on a private network and not accessibly directly from the web and you have a reverse proxy that maps the public ip to the local one. In the above instance, you only get Invalid Host header unless you add --disable-host-check also.

In this scenario, running the following

ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check

will load the page, but the websocket for live updates will not connect as it tries to use http://localhost:4200 which is obviously not accessible from the net :)